# AngularJs 1.x : Add Interceptor to an injected module

Tags: angularjs

I have my core module of my application . But I want to add an interceptor to a module which is getting injected into my core module. Can we do this?

Comment: Please provide more details, what interceptor, a HTTP one? Why does it have to be a different module?

Comment: yes the HTTP interceptor. I am using a module through which the http calls are done. So I want to add http interceptor for that module.

Comment: Read [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - Interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors).

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this just add the module to interceptor list